# Words that are their own past tense

Tags: tenses, past-tense, time

Does anyone know of a particular "rule" to know which words are their own past tense (such as "hurt"), and aren't modified for time? I'd like an easy rule to tell my students

Comment: You can do it only with a list. There are about 15 irregular verbs with three identical stem forms. All have the final consonant t, e.g. cut let hit put  -  hurt burst cast.

Comment: @rogermue:  and also the ones with final consonant "d", like spread and shed. Googling the examples will find you several lists of them.

Comment: @Peter Shor Right, a list of irregular verbs  and three identical  stem forms  ending with final d is also needed. I forgot.

Comment: My advice? Make them memorize a list of irregular verbs: In the long run, they will thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

**"to hurt" is an irregular verb** and irregular verbs are, well, irregular.  **There is no rule** and **the non-native student has to be introduced to them and learn them**.  Since there are so many of them, it would be sensible to omit those that are very rarely used.

Irregular verbs are those that don't form the past simple and past participle by adding "-ed" to the infinitive.  There are three groups of such verbs.

In the first group the past simple and past participle are just like the infinitive:

- cut, cut, cut
- put, put, put
- set, set, set

In the second group, only the past simple and the past participle are identical.

- buy, bought, bought
- win, won, won

Finally, in the third group, any form is different from the other two.

- go, went, gone
- take, took, taken.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_irregular_verbs)  the dozen most frequently used English verbs are all irregular.  For a complete list of irregular verbs, including verbs formed by adding prefixes to the infinitive (mistake, overdo, undergo, etc) see ["list of irregular verbs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_irregular_verbs).

Comment: For what it's worth, the third category ("strong verbs") tends to have its own internal rules, although they've been mutated over time. For example, an Anglo-Saxon i-stem verb is very likely to form it's past tense with *-o-* and its past participle with *-en*: hence *drive, drove, driven; ride, rode, ridden; strive, strove, striven; stride, strode, stridden; smite, smote, smitten; bide, bode, bidden; etc.* The verb *to dive* is currently toeing the line between strong and weak verbs, having acquired the past tense *dove* but resisting the past participle **diven*.

Comment: @Anonym  It's difficult to establish rules for the third category as different formations exist nowadays. (begun, sown, shown, rung, etc.)  I do agree, however, that the strong-type inflection "tends to have its own internal rules" but a student would have to learn which sub-group follows which rule, which imho wouldn't help much.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the student's learning style. I know that I remember material better when I understand the underlying patterns, however small their application may be.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a rule; it's a verb class. *Hurt* is a member of a small class of verbs (call them *hit, hurt, set*) that have unusual characteristics:

1. they're all monosyllables
2. they all end in *t* or *d*
3. they all have only one verb form

And the principal parts of these verbs (present, past, passive participle, like *go, went, gone*) are

*set, set, set* (also *upset, offset*, etc)
*cut, cut, cut* (also *recut*, etc)
*wet, wet, wet* (causative uses *wetted*)
*thrust, thrust, thrust* (also *rethrust*, etc.)
*hit, hit, hit*
*shit, shit, shit*
*put, put, put*
*let, let, let*
*hurt, hurt, hurt*
*split, split, split*
*cast, cast, cast*
*fit, fit, fit*
*cost, cost, cost*
*bet, bet, bet*
*bid, bid, bid*
*knit, knit, knit*
*quit, quit, quit*
*rid, rid, rid*
*shed, shed, shed*
*shut, shut, shut*
*spread, spread, spread*
*wed, wed, wed*

Comment: I know you know this, but for future visitors I'd like to point out there are actually two different *put* verbs, and these have distinctive inflectional patterns. Presumably because golf and putting greens are “new”, the *put* rhyming with *cut* and *shut* is regular with *put, putted, putted*. The  *put, put, put* that your post mentions is the older and more general-purpose *put* rhyming with *root* and *foot*.

Comment: The verb for golfing is spelled _putt_, with a double T, to comply with English spelling. So it's _putt, putted, putted_.