# Forecasted? Really?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, verbs

“Forecast” has always been past, present, and future. Lately I’m hearing and reading “forecasted” to describe weather or conditions that are to be expected. It sounds and reads as if an ignorant child is speaking. Has anyone else noticed? Am I wrong?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/267379). What this question shows is that not all forms are equally acceptable to all native speakers. Many young children say *He hitted me* or *It costed too much* before they learn any better.

Comment: On Google, "forecast expenses" returns 22,900 results, whereas "forecasted expenses" 52,100 results. In this case, I think the "forcasted" term is being used because "forecast expenses" looks like a compound noun formed by juxtoposition of the noun "forecast" and the noun "expenses", and could mean something like "the expenses related to creating the (noun) forecast". "forecasted expenses", however, looked like a past-participle "forecasted" modifying "expenses" meaning "these expenses have been forecast(ed)".

Answer (score 0):

Well, [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/forecast#:%7E:text=Word%20forms%3A%20plural%2C%203rd%20person,past%20tense%20and%20past%20participle.) has this *Language Note*:

> The forms ***forecast*** and ***forecasted*** *can both be used for the past tense and past participle*.

As this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forecast%20weather%20conditions%2C%20forecasted%20weather%20conditions&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows, *forecasted* is indeed less common form:
[image]

[Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/usage/forecast-forecasted/) agrees and says:

> Aside from the debate on the regular and irregular form of *forecast*, the word ***forecasted***’s other distinction with ***forecast*** is that it can be an adjective.
>
> As an adjective means that has been forecast–for example:
>
> - The ***forecasted*** sales depend on marketability and star power.

Comment: That doesn't provide any data on acceptability. Without real survey data, you can't know that.

Answer (score -1):

Both forms are correct. Here are some usage hints from the Grammarist:

> Forecast is both a regular and irregular verb such as laid that may stay in its base form for past and past participle forms. That means their past and past participle forms are still the -cast form instead of the variant -ed past participle. Here’s are some examples:

> - But at the same time, other studies have forecast that warmer temperatures will reduce the wind shear necessary to turn a routine thunderstorm into a powerful system that can give birth to tornadoes. [Time]

> - Last year, they forecast that a company’s corresponding pseudo-conglomerate returns dictate future price movements.

> You can also use it in regular form, meaning the simple past and past participle forms are forecasted. This situation is a rare instance in English verb morphology. In fact, any newly invented verb is usually regular before it becomes irregular.

> Even though regular verbs outnumber irregular verbs, forecasted is still less common than the irregular forecast–for example:

> - They forecasted a storm coming this weekend.
> - The organization forecasted the tax evader’s loss.
> - Snow is forecasted for tomorrow.